# BLDC hall sensor output to pulses

Tags: digital-logic, brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller, hall-effect

I want to combine the output of the three phases of the hall sensor output to generate a pulse for any change in the output of the hall sensor. Can someone suggest a circuit implementation to achieve this type of output?

Thanks in advance
-Sriram